# play 2.5 production mode not able to use the injected ConfigurationProvider class object in Singleton class which runs when application starts

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.5

I have a singleton class where I have injected ConfigurationProvider class in the constructor.

```
class Global {

    ConfigurationProvider configurationProvider;
    @Inject
    Global(ConfigurationProvider configurationProvider){
       this.configurationProvider = configurationProvider;

       DatabaseConfiguration.DB_URL = configurationProvider.get().getConfig("db").getString("default.url");
    }
}
```

When I try to access ConfigurationProvider class methods the object is not available and throws NullPointerException when I starts in test production mode(activator testProd)

I have binded the Global class in Module class

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule 
{
    @Override
    public void configure()
    {
        // Use the system clock as the default implementation of Clock
        bind(Clock.class).toInstance(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
        // Ask Guice to create an instance of ApplicationTimer when the
        // application starts.
        bind(ApplicationTimer.class).asEagerSingleton();
        // Set AtomicCounter as the implementation for Counter.
        bind(Counter.class).to(AtomicCounter.class);
        bind(Global.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating instance of Global, it should be created through dependency injection. and ConfigurationProvider should be concrete class as you haven't specified binding for it.

Comment: I have mentioned Global class as singleton and initializing it in the Module class as mentioned above. I want to read for application.conf file inside that singleton class. That's why I tried injecting ConfigurationProvider class in Global class.

Comment: Have you injected this Global class somewhere?

Comment: As mentioned above I just bind Global class as singleton in Module class. Its injected as part of configuration in Module class and getting called when the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Module you have created by adding

**play.modules.enabled += "modules.Module"**

in your **application.conf** file. So that dependency bindings will be configured.

Comment: I have configured this in application.conf. Not working yet.